# pydantic, but one field an iterator

Tags: python, pydantic

I have some very big json files that I'm trying to use pydantic models for - however, the memory usage is starting to become untenable. The project started when the files were not nearly as big, but as things progressed, the json files exploded in size.

I have one particular key in the json file that is a list, and contains ~95% of the data. It's a long list, so being able to iterate over those objects, and build them on-demand in an iterator style might go a long way to making this problem palatable.

Is there an obvious way in pydantic (or non-obvious) to *not* construct the objects for every object in the field, but instead, construct them on demand? Nothing has made itself obvious from the documentation.

Note that I'm currently constrained to pydantic v1, but if v2 is the only option, I can go on a mission to convince the rest of the company to update. Thanks!

Comment: Could you share your models and an example `json` data?